# Is there a better way to generator/publish data at given Frequency other then using the clock() function

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, generator, frequency, rate

I have to generate & publish data (as protocol buffer messages) with a frequency of 1Hz and I have been thinking of alternatives to just sticking it into a While loop with a clock() function. Maybe I am over thinking the issue but any advice on the matter would be much appreciated thanks

Comment: better in terms of what? if you need fixed frequency over long period you should apply corrections, if you only care about the distance between two events then not

Comment: It would be helpful to provide samples of the code you have tried - that way it will be easier for people to provide useful solutions.

Comment: You can use `chrono` to get a current time. Then you can use `std::this_thread` to sleep until 1s from then. Put this in a while loop and your thread will wake up once per second.

Answer (score 2):

There are *many* ways to call a function on a regular interval. Which one is best depends on the situation and needs of the program. There's no single "best way".

A few possibilities (there are many more):

Sit in a loop and sleep for some duration every time round the loop. Simple, easy to understand. But rarely the best solution, since nothing else can happen while you sleep.

Sit in a loop waiting for some event to occur. Like a timer event. Process each event as it arrives - if not enough time has passed, ignore the event (maybe).

Set up a timer with a callback function that will call the function at regular intervals.

If your intervals are *very* tiny, then maybe spin / busy-wait in a loop and check elapsed time each time around the loop and do something when enough time has passed (rarely a good idea since it will burn a lot of CPU time doing nothing, but *sometimes* it's the right option).

Comment: Setting up a timer with a callback function sounds like a good possibility. Thanks for the help